# Why does sampling interval affect system response quite drastically?

Tags: linear-regulator

I have been given a 2nd order transfer function in continuous time domain and been asked to design a feedback regulator and an observer for it.

The initial closed-loop system's transfer function is:
\$\frac{{\;\;\;\;\;\;100s + 500}}{{{s^2} + 105s + 506}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaSaaaeaaca
% aMe8UaaGjbVlaaysW7caaMe8UaaGjbVlaaysW7caaIXaGaaGimaiaa
% icdacaWGZbGaey4kaSIaaGynaiaaicdacaaIWaaabaGaam4CamaaCa
% aaleqabaGaaGOmaaaakiabgUcaRiaaigdacaaIWaGaaGynaiaadoha
% cqGHRaWkcaaI1aGaaGimaiaaiAdaaaaaaa!4EA5!
\$

To discretize the system, I can select whatever sampling interval I like. However, selecting a different sampling interval, will change overal system's response significantly. For instance, this is my system's response with sampling interval T=0.1 sec to a unit step input:

[image]

The overal system's transfer function is (including feedback regulator and deadbeat observer):

[image]

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Compared to this one with T=0.0001:

[image]

The overal system's transfer function is:
[image]

My question is how to justify the differences in responses.

(Above plots are simply step responses to mentioned transfer functions)
Regards

Comment: This seems odd to me. You are sampling your continuous time signal after your system, is it right? Can you also add the continuous time response?

Comment: Can you give us the system and the comand you are using to discretize?

Comment: This is the approach I followed:

- I converted the transfer function to controllable canonical form (state-space) using Matlab `ss` command
- Discretized the system using `c2d` command
- Using `place` command to work out the the feedback matrix (two desired poles have been already given to me for this mean)
- Forming observability matrix using `obsv` command and hence using relevant equation to work out the observer
- Finding the overall system's transfer function (including regulator and observer) and apply `step` to see the response.

Comment: The difference between the steady state values at 20 seconds suggests to me that these aren't really showing everything that's going on. If the equations really were the same I'd have expected them to have the same steady state error, with the same given input. Somewhere, the inputs or the system is different, or steady state hasn't actually been achieved in one or the other.

Comment: @SeanBoddy Everything is the same in the code. I simply changed the value of `T` in the code and pasted the output plots straight away.

Comment: You could get this with under-sampling i.e. aliasing. Although the top graph looks like a low pass filter, it could be a high pass filter (like the bottom graph) but its low sampling rate could be exactly under-sampling a signal of the right frequency and producing aliasing i.e. a dc offset.

Comment: Are you placing poles after you discretize? That may be your problem: poles of continuos systems are not the same for discrete - as example, continuous poles are stable with real part negative, discrete poles are stable with norm less than 1. Even worse, continuous ->discrete pole placement is totally dependent on T, so that may explain the diference on outputs.

You can use step directly on the system given by c2d. Compare those two before anything else.

Comment: You still haven't provided your equation. Until we see that, I'm as confused as you are. It settles in the same amount of time, but at a different steady state with 100 times less input. A qualitative analysis of the equation itself is the best way to proceed.

Comment: @MdxBhmt
You are absolutely right with your guess. I do place poles after discretization (in fact that is part of the design criteria). The system's response to the output of `c2d` command (before pole placement) looks as it should i.e. sampling interval can make the response either smoother or more rough.
@SeanBoddy
I added them to the first post.

Comment: It's always a good idea to use minreal on any transfer function before printing.

Comment: Are you using the same pole placement for both timesteps or are you ajusting them? Remember $s_i ~ (z_i-1)/T$

Comment: @MdxBhmt Thanks for the `minreal` tip. I was totally unaware of such function in Matlab. It rephrased the `TF` to second order ! In regard to your question, 'yes' I used the same pole placement for both transfer functions above.

Answer (score 1):

Pole performance on discrete systems are dependent on T - the timestep.

You want the following:

$$S_i = \frac{ Z_i-1}{T} = \frac{Z_i'-1}{T'}$$

If you don't adjust accordingly, the step response will wildly change, as seen in your case, a second order system became a differentiator (with dominant zero)

If you don't adjust Z_i' for T', the equivalent pole placement is

$$S_i'=\frac{Z_i'-1}{T'}=\frac{Z_i-1}{T'}=\frac{T}{T'}S_i$$

Since T' is made smaller, T/T' makes S_i' bigger - thus faster.

Since the zeroes are unchanged, the poles are relatively faster than the zeroes, meaning they are less dominant. That's why the system approach a differentiator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not quite sure if I understood your explanation correctly or not. First, can you please clarify how did you work out above equations? what are S_i and Z_i parameters? Moreover, as far as I can say from your answer, such major changes in two step responses with two significantly different sampling intervals are normal due to your rational. But nothing wrong with selecting T=0.0001 for my design. Right?

Comment: That's right. S_i is the equivalent pole on continuous system. Z_i is the discrete pole.

The formula above is the 'forward aproximation' of the S->Z transform.

http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/4161BC2AFF6B822886256DDD0065F240

They come from manipulating Z=e^(sT)